# How to put different color random dots in a rectangle separated by a diagonal (JAVA)

Tags: java, random

My problem is that I cant get the diagonal to resize properly. If I run the code the diagonal is on the wrong side and when I expand it vertically it doesn't maintain a perfect diagonal from one corner to another.

Below I have my code for the program and the driver.
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

```
public class Points
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Points");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  PointsPanel panel = new PointsPanel();

  frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
  }
  }
```

Here is the main program

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.lang.Math.*;

public class PointsPanel extends JPanel
{
 private final int MAX_POINTS = 20000;
 private final int LENGTH = 1;
 private int x,x1,y,y1;
 private Random random;
 double slope,b,c,g;


 public PointsPanel(){
  random = new Random();
  setBackground(Color.black);
  setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

 }


 public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
 {
  super.paintComponent(page);
 for(int count = 0; count < MAX_POINTS; count++)
 {

  x = random.nextInt(getWidth()-1) + 1;

  y = random.nextInt(getHeight()-1) + 1;

  x1= x + LENGTH;
  y1= y + LENGTH;

  slope = x1/y1;
    c = slope*x;
    b = ((-1)*(y))-c;
    g = (-1)*y1;

  if (b <= g)

     page.setColor(Color.red);
  else
     page.setColor(Color.green);
     page.drawLine(x,y,x1,y1);
 }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved your issue by making a little change to your PointsPanel class. Take a look at PointsPanel2 class. **First of all the diagonal is a linear equation of the form y = aX + b and since it passes by the points of coordinate (0,0) we can reduce it to y = aX therefore a = Y/X for any (X,Y) point that is part of the diagonal.**

Now event though the drawing methods use integer coordinate **we still have to compute the a coefficient as a floating number (like a double), otherwise it won't work because of rounding issues**.

Then once the other part of your code runs and we obtain (x,y) then x1 and y1, all I have to do is to compute the corresponding diagonal y for x1 and compare it to y1 and depending on the obtained value, change the color to red or green

Use this PointsPanel2 class instead of PointsPanel to test with your other Points class

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.lang.Math.*;

public class PointsPanel2 extends JPanel
{
     private final int MAX_POINTS = 20000;
     private final int LENGTH = 1;
     private int x,x1,y,y1;
     private Random random;
     double slope,b,c,g;


     public PointsPanel2(){
     random = new Random();
     setBackground(Color.black);
     setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

 }


 public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
 {
      super.paintComponent(page);
      // Diagonal equation
      // X0, Y0 = (0,0)
      // Xl, Yl = width, height
      // Equation y = aX + b
      // 0 = 0 + b ==> b = 0
      // Yl = aXl ==> a = Yl/Xl

      // Computes the diagonal a coefficient
      double aCoeff = (getHeight()*1.0)/(getWidth()*1.0);
      System.out.println("Xl,Yl, a = " + getWidth() + " " + getHeight() + "   " + aCoeff);

      for(int count = 0; count < MAX_POINTS; count++)
      {

          x = random.nextInt(getWidth()-1) + 1;

          y = random.nextInt(getHeight()-1) + 1;

          x1= x + LENGTH;
          y1= y + LENGTH;

          // Computes the diagonal image of x in order to compare it with y1
          double diagImage = aCoeff * x1;

          slope = x1/y1;
          c = slope*x;
          b = ((-1)*(y))-c;
          g = (-1)*y1;

          //if (b <= g)
          if (diagImage <= y1)
              page.setColor(Color.red);
          else
              page.setColor(Color.green);
          page.drawLine(x,y,x1,y1);
        }
     }
 }
```